# 'unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)' on my iOS app with Youtube API v3

Tags: ios, youtube

I am developing about function of uploading video to YouTube for my iOS app.
So I use GTLYoutube libraries for YouTube API v3.

I think OAuth2 step is maybe succeeded on my app.

But when my app uploads video to YouTube using following method,
my app crashes with this  error every time:

> unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)

Upload Method:

```
(void)uploadVideoWithVideoObject:(GTLYouTubeVideo *)video
           resumeUploadLocationURL:(NSURL *)locationURL
```

Please give me advice!

Comment: is this a method you wrote or is there a method like this uploadVideoWithVideoObject

Answer (score 0):

self.rpcUploadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/rpc?uploadType=resumable&prettyPrint=false"];